# How to create Angular 5 HttpClient instance in Typescript class

Tags: angular, typescript, get, undefined, httpclient

I'm writing a base class which contains the httpClient.  It is used to make REST api calls.  The httpClient variable is set correctly if defined in constructor, but not in private variable.

Here's my sample code:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyBaseClass implements {
  private httpClient = HttpClient

  constructor(
    private httpClient2: HttpClient
  ) {
    console.log("httpClient2", httpClient2)
    console.log("httpClient2.get", httpClient2.get)
  }
  callApi() {
    console.log("httpClient", this.httpClient)
    console.log("httpClient.get", this.httpClient.get)
  }
}
```

**constructor output:**
[image]

**callApi output:**
[image]

As you can see the two variables aren't the same and the get property of httpClient is undefined.

I would use the variable in the constructor throughout my class, but I what I want is to extend this class and having the variable in the constructor isn't convenient.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Will

Comment: Can you make your base class in such a way that the derived classes don't need a specific constructor?

Comment: If you mean the subclass, then no.  I have to run "super()" as my first statement in the constructor subclass.

Comment: Do you absolutely need a constructor in the derived class?

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I think I do need them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is another option if you really don't want to inject the services in your base class' constructor.

1.
Declare a global variable containing a ref to the injector and assign it in your module (or somewhere else, before your base class'constructor is called)

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

export let InjectorInstance: Injector;

export class AppModule 
{
  constructor(private injector: Injector) 
  {
    InjectorInstance = this.injector;
  }
}
```

2
Then you can use it like this in your base class

```
import {InjectorInstance} from '../app.module';

export class MyBaseClass  
{
    private httpClient : HttpClient:

    constructor()
    {
        this.httpClient = InjectorInstance.get<HttpClient>(HttpClient);
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll check it out.  If works, I will probably make this my answer...thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The property `httpClient` on your class is simply being set to the `HttpClient` class constructor. If you need an instance of that class, you need to let Angular provide it to you via dependency injection like your `httpClient2` property (i.e. as a parameter to your constructor).

As a note, adding the `private` accessor to the parameter on the constructor is syntactic sugar that is doing the following:

```
class MyBaseClass {
    private httpClient2: HttpClient;

    constructor(httpClient2: HttpClient) {
        this.httpClient2 = httpClient2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really want to avoid injecting it in the constructor.

Comment: Why?... That is how you do things properly in Angular

Comment: Without using dependency injection, you will make it difficult to properly test things, especially when you need to start mocking things like network calls

Comment: When I extend MyBaseClass, in the subclass I want to be able to call super().  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Your base class will need to have the `HttpClient` injected into its constructor and you pass it as a parameter in your `super()` call

Comment: So every subclass, I would call something like super(httpClient), is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is what you would do

Comment: The TypeScript documentation has a section on inheritance discussing this  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: Not the answer I'm looking for, but I'll do it if I have to.  I thought by subclassing, the base class would handle most of the leg works.

Comment: The only other thing you could do to prevent that would be instead of using inheritance you could use composition (meaning passing an instance of this base functionality class as parameter injected into what would have been your subclasses)

Comment: Not familiar with the technique you mentioned (composition), if you have a link like the inheritance, that would be great...thanks.

Comment: Here is a plunker showing the difference. Take a look at the example.ts file https://plnkr.co/edit/YvKxFnTTg5hijjqlm0HF

Here is a wiki article on Object Composition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I see what you did there.  I'm sticking with extends for now.  Not crazy about the Dependency Injection stuff, but it'll do for now...thanks.  +1 from me.