# No provider for HttpHeaders in Angluar 12

Tags: angular, angular12

I am getting this error below when I try to use the get and post methods in a component. I tried to extend but it seems that that is no longer possible as `HttpClient` is `final`. Even then, I got the same error.

```
  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(LayerListModule)[LayerListService -> EsriHttp -> EsriHttp -> HttpHeaders -> HttpHeaders -> HttpHeaders]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHeaders!
  NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(LayerListModule)[LayerListService -> EsriHttp -> EsriHttp -> HttpHeaders -> HttpHeaders -> HttpHeaders]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHeaders!
      at NullInjector.get (core.js:11101)
      at R3Injector.get (core.js:11268)
      at R3Injector.get (core.js:11268)
      at R3Injector.get (core.js:11268)
      at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4751)
      at ɵɵinject (core.js:4755)
      at injectArgs (core.js:4832)
      at Object.factory (core.js:11522)
      at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11438)
      at R3Injector.get (core.js:11257)
      at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213)
      at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167)
      at zone.js:1279
      at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
      at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28660)
      at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
      at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
      at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582)
      at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491)
      at invokeTask (zone.js:1600)
  defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6479
  handleError @ core.js:6527
  next @ core.js:29284
  __tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
  next @ Subscriber.js:122
  _next @ Subscriber.js:72
  next @ Subscriber.js:49
  next @ Subject.js:39
  emit @ core.js:25936
  (anonymous) @ core.js:28699
  invoke @ zone.js:372
  run @ zone.js:134
  runOutsideAngular @ core.js:28572
  onHandleError @ core.js:28699
  handleError @ zone.js:376
  runGuarded @ zone.js:147
  api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:1074
  drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:589
  invokeTask @ zone.js:491
  invokeTask @ zone.js:1600
  globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1626
```

Is there anything I am missing in the code below?

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  
  @Injectable()
  export class EsriHttp {
    private _http: HttpClient;
    get(url: string, options?: {headers?: {[header: string]: string | string[]} }): Observable<any> {
      options = this.setOptions(options);
      return this._http.get(url, options);
    }
  
    post(url: string, body: any, options?: {headers?: {[header: string]: string | string[]} }): Observable<any> {
      options = this.setOptions(options);
      body = this.transformRequest(body);
      return this._http.post(url, body, options);
    }
  
    private setOptions(options?: {headers?: {[header: string]: string | string[]}}) {
      if (options == null) {
        options = {headers: null };
  
      }
      if (options.headers === null) {
          options.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
      }
  
      return options;
    }
  
    private transformRequest(body) {
      if (!body.hasOwnProperty("f")) {
        body.f = "json";
      }
      let transform = (obj: any) => {
        let str = [];
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
          str.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
        });
        return str.join("&");
      };
      return transform(body);
    }
  }
```

Comment: httpClient should be injected via constructor like `constructor(private _http: HttpClient){}`

Comment: Then EsriHttp requires one parameter. What should I add there?

Comment: WHere `EsriHttp` requires one parameter?

Comment: Yes, when I add a constructor of httpclient, the IDE says one parameter required.

Comment: Can you share the error code/image

Comment: Sure `   constructor(private _http: HttpClient){}
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    An argument for '_http' was not provided.
`

Comment: You need to read up on dependency injection I think. You also want to DI EsriHttp where ever you are using it..

Comment: @MikeOne could you share with me a link with relevant example or article? This doesn't talk about an argument. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: @wondim can you share your code at https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @navnath thank you! My code is complex but anyways, I got the answer in another SO post. I will share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49316405/3674573) even though the usage is slightly different.

My app.module.ts

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

export let InjectorInstance: Injector; // Move it to top otherwise, @NgModule will throw an error

export class AppModule {
   constructor(private injector: Injector) {
   InjectorInstance = this.injector;
 }
}
```

My service file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {InjectorInstance} from '../app.module';

@Injectable()
export class EsriHttp{
   private _http: HttpClient;
  constructor(){
     this._http = InjectorInstance.get<HttpClient>(HttpClient);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: {headers?: {[header: string]: string | string[]} }): Observable<any> {
    options = this.setOptions(options);
    return this._http.get(url, options);
  }
  // The same for post method
```